# Iterate Calculation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to Haskell, I am trying to create an infinite list in haskell where the next term is found by the following formula

```
xn+1 = (xn + const / xn) div 2.
```

I have been looking into the iterate command as I want to apply the same function again to generate the next answer.

I will then use take to choose a certain number of elements from the list.

However I am unsure how I can represent xn when using iterate.

I started writing `take 10 (iterate (xn +5 /xn div 2) 1)`, I know I need to replace the xn but not sure what with.

Could somebody advise me?

Comment: It is `div (xn + const / xn) 2`. `div` is not an operator so you can not use it infix (without backtics).

Comment: I have been using div with the backticks, I removed them here as it took div out of the code listing when I did that.

Comment: @JamesHamish You have to escape the quote by putting a backslash before it: `\`div\``

Comment: quote backticks-containing code by putting double-backticks around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically describe a function:

```
next xn = (xn + c) / (2*xn)
```

with `c` the `const` (`const` is a function from the Prelude, so do not use that name). Or as a lambda expression:

```
\xn -> (xn + c) / (2*xn)
```

with `c` your constant. So now we can inject that in the `iterate`:

```
take 10 (iterate (\xn -> (xn + 5) / (2*xn)) 1)
```

with `c=5`, we get:

```
Prelude> take 10 (iterate (\xn -> (xn + 5) / (2*xn)) 1)
[1.0,3.0,1.3333333333333333,2.375,1.5526315789473684,2.110169491525424,1.684738955823293,1.9839094159713946,1.7601381796335236,1.9203430326819695]
```

If you want to calculate values over integers, you can use:

```
\xn -> div (xn + c) (2*xn)
```

this produces:

```
Prelude> take 10 (iterate (\xn -> div (xn + 5) (2*xn)) 1)
[1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3]
```

If you want to round down the result after the calculation, you can use `floor`:

```
\xn -> floor ((fromIntegral xn + 5) / (2* fromIntegral xn))
```

this produces:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ iterate (\xn -> floor ((fromIntegral xn + 5) / (2* fromIntegral xn))) 1
[1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3]
```

Comment: The problem with this is I am  using div for integral divide and rounding down, when you have divided you are using /

Comment: You can not use `div` and `/` at the same time and obtain the same type, since `(/) :: Fractional f => f -> f -> f` and `div :: Integral i => i -> i -> i`. Although technically we can construct such a type, it is quite weird to have a type bing both `Integral` and `Fractional`.

Comment: @JamesHamish check whether  the parentheses are in fact what you intended, or not. And it makes much more sense with the floats than with the integers.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `lambda` function:

```
mySeq = iterate (\xn ->(xn + 5 `div` xn) `div` 2) 1
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/Nw89/0)